# In which case I need to call finish() method on click back button..?

Tags: android, android-activity

What are the scenarios in which I should call finish() method on back button or it is good to call it on each back button..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depend on your app requirement, for example:

case 1: when press back, need over your activity, so you need invoke `finish`, this is default

case 2: in one activity, has 3 step, like *a->b->c*, if you in the step b or c, you press back just want to back previous step, to b or to a, so you dont need invoke `finish` method in `onBackPressed`

so, above just a example, you need make a better choice in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

When we came back from the second activity to the first activity in second activity will use this finish() to close the second activity and going back to first activity .

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your requirement... i m using finish()

1) when someone select EXIT option from menu

2) In my login acitity .. so that user doesnt see the login box again on press back button from post login page